# Tikz 3D plot of poles zeros

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I need to make a 3D plot in tikz of the form as in the picture. It's the magnitude plot of transfer function

H(s)= (s+1)(s+2)/(s+3)(s+1+j)(s+1-j)

I am sorry, I have not shared any attempt because I am ignorant in tikz 3d plotting. If somebody provide the solution, it will be kick start for me and then I build up on it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

My Attempt and still few things to rectify.

I have plotted the graph with online help of different resources (code and picture attached).

Now the problems are

- It is not correcting plotting the curve in y-z plane the red line and give this error message

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots expected to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with [samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.

- Labels are too small and not placed properly.
- If somebody can set view angles so it looks like the picture of the book.

If somebody can help in that regard.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={H(\x,\y) = 3*((((((\x)^2-(\y)^2+3*(\x)+2)^2+((2*\x*\y)+3*\y)^2)+2.2204e-16)^(1/2))/(((((\x)^3+5*(\x)^2-3*\x*(\y)^2+8*x-5*(\y)^2+6)^2+(3*(\x)^2*y+10*\x*\y-(\y)^3+8*y)^2)+2.2204e-16)^(1/2)));}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[    
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    width=50cm, 
    view={30}{10},      
    xmin=-4,
    xmax=0,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=5,
    miter limit=1,   
    xlabel=$\sigma$,
    xlabel style={anchor=east,xshift=-5pt,at={(xticklabel* cs:.95)}}, 
    ylabel=$j\Omega$,
    zlabel=$\mathopen| H(s)\mathclose|$,
    zlabel style={anchor=north east},
    xtick = {-3,-2,-1,0},
    hide obscured x ticks=false,
    ytick = {-1,0,1},
    ztick = {2,4},
    ]

\addplot3[
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=gray,
        line width=0.1pt, 
        fill=white,
        domain=-4:0,
        y domain = -2:2,
        samples = 50,
        samples y = 50,
        restrict z to domain*=0:5]
        {H(\x,\y)};

\addplot3[domain=-2:2,samples=70, samples y = 0,red, thick] ({0},{x},{H(0,x)});


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You still need to try to do it. Search this site or google for "PGFPlots" or "Latex 3D surface plot". Make a minimal example and explain where/if you are stuck.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383343/complicated-surface-plot-projection-and-cut.  I found closest this one but it's not completely understandable. Why ellipses are used.

Comment: Start by making a plot and worry about details later. Make a document, make 3D axis(I recommend "PGFPlots"), make some surface, make your surface, .... Here is a place to start: https://pgfplots.net/surface-plot-math/

Comment: these contain some useful info https://youtu.be/bIY6ahHVgqA and https://youtu.be/NtoIXhUgqSk

Comment: I managed to draw the graph just have to understand the transfer function s domain values into x,y. Now the problems is draw YZ domain line and labels.